# overgrowing and well-tended in the same sentence

Tags: word-meaning

I'm wondering if there's anything odd about the following sentence:

The well-tended plant is overgrowing its pot.

I'd appreciate your help.

Comment: Well, logically if the plant were "well-tended", it would be in a larger pot (or in the ground) already.

Answer (score 1):

That statement is grammatically well-formed but there is some semantic dissonance if tending a plant well includes sizing the pot appropriately and doing so in anticipation of the need. That semantic dissonance would happen in *any* language, so this isn't really a question about English. Hence my -1.  If you prefer, I could vote to close on the grounds that "anything odd" is too vague.

Comment: Thank you. Actually, I was just seeking confirmation of my suspicions. The sentence occurs in an ESL book.

Comment: The sentence could be improved (semantically) by changing **is overgrowing** to **would soon overgrow**.

Comment: Or by changing **well-tended** to **thriving**.